# CSS color transitions do not work as expected in Chrome/Edge 83

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I'm having trouble with css transitions.
This code works in IE, Firefox and also worked in some older Chrome versions. I cannot tell exactly which. But it does not work as expected in Chrome and Edge 83. See the attached snippet.

While scrolling the document, background and foreground colors should change smoothly between the sections.

What happens in Chrome and Edge 83: The text and border colors transition to black for some reason. Not always, but most of the time.

If you disable the transition in css, it works as expected but the colors jump of course.

What's going on here?

Edit: Still broken in 84

```js
var f = (function () {

    var _pages = [];

    var _init = function() {
        __init();
    };

    var _updateScroll = function() {
        let doc = document.documentElement,
            scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0),
            currentPage = 0;

        for ( let i = 0; i < _pages.length; i++ ) {
            if ( scrollTop <= _pages[i] ) {
                break;
            } else {
                currentPage = i;
            }
        }
        document.querySelector('html').className = 'theme-'+currentPage;
    };

    var __init = function() {
        _calc();
        window.onresize = _calc;
        document.onscroll = _updateScroll;
    };


    var _calc = function() {
        _wh = window.innerHeight;
        _pages = [];
        let pages = document.querySelectorAll('body > .page');
        pages.forEach( function( p ) {
            let o = p.offsetTop;
            _pages.push( o );
        });
        _updateScroll();
    };

    return {
        init            : _init
    }

})();

f.init();
```

```css
html,body {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    margin:0;
}

.frame {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-color: inherit;
    padding:20px;
}

html.theme-0 {
    background-color: #707;
    color: #0ff;
    border-color: #0ff;
}

html.theme-1 {
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #00f;
    border-color: #00f;
}

html.theme-2 {
    background-color: #0f0;
    color: #f0f;
    border-color: #f0f;
}

html.theme-3 {
    background-color: #ff0;
    color: #307;
    border-color: #307;
}
```

```html
<html class="theme-0">
    <body>
        <div class="page page-0">
            <div class="frame">
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
                0<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page page-1">
            <div class="frame">
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
                1<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page page-2">
            <div class="frame">
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
                2<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page page-3">
            <div class="frame">
            3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
                3<br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting. Definitely looks like a [bug in Chrome](https://imgur.com/a/c9tudzy), here. And yes, it works "sometimes" 